# Command Prompt is not working for me with Python 3.10.2

Tags: python, command, command-prompt

So I was trying to use command prompt just basic functions like dir and cd but neither of them work:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.493]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\niela>python
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dir
<built-in function dir>
>>> cd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?
>>>
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be here?

Comment: The problem is that once you typed `python` you executed python shell. Type `exit()` or  Ctrl + Z to close it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght is correct.  You need to understand that you are either `[1]` in the python shell (for python code), or `[2]` in the command prompt (for dos commands).

Comment: When you run python within the command prompt shell, it spawns a second mini-shell, which has a different command set. It's a coincidence that both Python and command prompt share the `dir` command nane, but this doesn't do the same thing in each.

Answer (score 0):

CD is a command prompt exclusive so if you want to write python in your command prompt use cd to navigate to the directory you want to work in first then type `python` or use `ctrl + Z` to escape the python section the cd to the directory you want to use